# Strange window behavior

Tags: pantheon, gala

Please take a look at the picture!

[image]

[image]

[image]

On the first two images Smartgit latest version 18.2.3 #13220. On the third image of PlayOnLinux 4.2.12. I ask you to correct this behavior of windows

Comment: It looks that you've installed a theme so that could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Maccer, no, it has nothing to do with my dark theme. Here is a image of the standard theme - https://imgur.com/gQIS0fB

Comment: Alright so diggin a bit I found the solution I think! Check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [known bug](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/244) that may be out of the scope of elementary. Anyway the fix is to run the app with `GTK_CSD=0`. You can do this from the command line:

```
GTK_CSD=0 playonlinux
```

And you can also modify the .desktop file so that it works automatically when you open the app. You just need to find the line starting with `Exec=` and add `env GTK_CSD=0` to it so it looks like

```
Exec=env GTK_CSD=0 /path/to/playonlinux
```

Comment: For PlayOnlinux, your option is the solution, but not for SmartGit. Any other suggestions? And thanks for helping! Look at this https://imgur.com/a/f5boNmc

Comment: I don't really know... The other possible solutions listed on that bug report involve fixes that will break other stuff and it's difficult to repair. You should post an answer there and hope some dev can help you.